# android background image scale by cropping

Tags: android, layout, background, crop

I want to add a background image to my layout by adding a big image and then set android dynamically crop my image from center for different android devices. I have tried lots of ways  but i cant find any way of doing this specific job.

Comment: Show what you have tried, and preferably screen captures. It will be easier to help you.

Comment: use `gravity` in your `BitmapDrawable`

Comment: stack overflow doesn't let me to post pictures. but i have tried tools like 9 patch resizer(didn't help at all), simple 9 patch generator(it stretches photo except cropping) it tried some basic codes like padding and margins etc. nothing worked out.